# setTitleWithRepresentedFilename not changing NSWindows filename?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nsdocument

I have a `NSDocument` that I am calling:

```
[self.windowForSheet setTitleWithRepresentedFilename: @"hello"];
```

On, but the windows title does not change. It displays `MyApp -- Untitled 1`. I have also tried:

```
[self.windowForSheet setTitleWithRepresentedFilename: @"hello"];
[self.windowForSheet display];
```

But still it does not get updated.

I have confirmed that `self.windowForSheet` is not nil. Am I doing this incorrectly? Note that I am expecting the 'Untitled 1' part of the title to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setTitleWithRepresentedFilename`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nswindow/1419192-settitlewithrepresentedfilename?language=objc) uses a `filePath`, not an arbitrary text string; I think you are probably looking for [`title`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nswindow/1419404-title?language=objc) perhaps.

If `@"hello"` is not an actual path of a file, then using it with `setTitleWithRepresentedFilename` is likely not going to return the name of the file, which in turn won't change the title of the window.